# How to remove nonnumeric junk from a file

Tags: regex, bash, text, sed

Here's an output from `less`:

```
487451
487450<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
487449<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
487448<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
487447<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
487446<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
487445<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
484300<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
484299<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
484297<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
484296<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
484295<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
484294<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
484293<A3><BA>1<A3><BA>1
483496
483495
483494
483493
483492
483491
```

I see a bunch of nonprintable characters here. How do I remove them using `sed`/`tr`?

My try was `'s/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1/g'`, but it doesn't work.

**EDIT**: Okay, let's go further down the source. The numbers are extracted from this file:

```
487451"><img src="Manage/pic/20100901/Adidas running-429.JPG" alt="Adidas running-429" height="120" border="0" class="BK01" onload='javascript:if(this.width>160){this.width=160}' /></a></td>
487450"><img src="Manage/pic/20100901/Adidas fs 1<A3><BA>1-060.JPG" alt="Adidas fs 1<A3><BA>1-060" height="120" border="0" class="BK01" onload='javascript:if(this.width>160){this.width=160}' /></a></td>
```

The first line is perfectly normal and what most of the lines are. The second is "corrupted". I'd just like to extract the number at the beginning (using `'s/\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/g'`, but somehow the nonprintables get into the regex, which should stop at `"`.

**EDIT II**: Here's a clarification: **There are no brackets in the text file.** These are character codes of nonprintable characters. The brackets are there because I copied the file from `less`. Mac's Terminal, on the other hand, uses `??` to represent such characters. I bet `xterm` on my Ubuntu would print that white oval with a question mark.

Comment: Do you want to remove `<A3>` in output or just want to replace that with `3`?

Comment: I want to remove everything after the first six digits (it's six only here, it varies in the actual file).

Comment: Alright, I posted my answer below. Please try and let me know.

Comment: The is the most amazing guide if you ever wanna use unix regex: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm

Answer (score 7):

Classic job for either `sed`'s or Unix's `tr` command.

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g' $file
```

(Anything that is not a digit - or newline - is deleted.)

```
tr -cd '0-9\012' < $file > $file.1
```

Delete (`-d`) the complement (`-c`) of the digits and newline...

Comment: I've already tried that `tr` and it gives me `tr: Illegal byte sequence`. I don't think it wants to read the nonprintables.

Comment: Then you must be running in a UTF-8 locale (or something similar), but reading an 8859-1 file.  The data is not valid UTF-8, so you can't process it with the UTF-8 locale set using programs that are aware of locale.  That is a source of irritation to all concerned.  The simplest workaround may be to set LANG=C in the environment, and see whether that is sufficient.  It may not be sufficient; you may have to set LC_CTYPE (or LC_ALL) to something that uses 8859-1 instead.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the bit where you match the rest of the line.

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)[^0-9]*/\1/g' 
                      ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the crap will always be inside brackets, why not delete that crap?

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

EDIT: Thanks, Mike that makes sense. In that case, how about:

```
sed 's/([0-9]+).*/\1/g'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the brackets are just less's way of representing nonprintable characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed command:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/' file.txt
```

#### OUTPUT (running above command on the input file you provided)

```
487451
487450
487449
487448
487447
487446
487445
484300
484299
484297
484296
484295
484294
484293
483496
483495
483494
483493
483492
483491
```

Comment: Nope, no change, (tested by `diff`ing the `od`s). :-(

Comment: @Mike: I provided you my output also from the above sed command. Is that not what you expect the output to be? And I tested it both on Linux and Mac.

Answer (score -2):

If the data always is like the sample, deleting from the less-than to the end of the line would work fine.
    sed -i "s/<.*$//" file

Comment: Please re-read the question. There is no less-than character in the file.